# update values from dropdown list in gridview to sql after button click in vb.net

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I have to update the values from dropdown list to sql. The dropdown list is in gridview using template field and I have to update the selected value to sql server. I have employee IDs in gridview and I want to update the status against the specific employee IDs.

[image]

Comment: [DataGridViewCell Combobox Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652957/what-event-catches-a-change-of-value-in-a-combobox-in-a-datagridviewcell)

Comment: Post what you have tried.