# Trigger selected value changed event on DataGridView.ComboBoxColumn

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox, datagridviewcomboboxcolumn

Currently, when a value is selected within the DataGridViewColumn with ComboBoxes, user has to click off that cell in order for the values to refresh via `CellValueChanged` Event on the DataGridView.

What I am trying to achieve is that as soon as a value is selected in a ComboBox the refresh is triggered.

Below is what I tried doing, so that when the drop-down is opened/closed it would trigger the refresh, but it only executes when the ComboBox is clicked on and the drop-down is visible, not when a value is selected.

```
Private Sub PL_DGV_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles PL_DGV.EditingControlShowing
        Dim cb As ComboBox = TryCast(e.Control, ComboBox)
        If cb IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim editingComboBox As ComboBox = DirectCast(e.Control, ComboBox)

            RemoveHandler editingComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged,
                New EventHandler(AddressOf editingComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged)

            AddHandler editingComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged,
                New EventHandler(AddressOf editingComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged)
        End If

End Sub

Private Sub editingComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim dgvc As DataGridViewCell = TryCast(Me.PL_DGV.CurrentCell, DataGridViewCell)

    RefreshCarriage(dgvc.RowIndex)

End Sub
```

Comment: This is OT but why are you casting twice? Inside the `If` block, you already have a reference to the `ComboBox` in `cb`, so why are you casting a second time and assigning to another variable? Get rid of `editingComboBox` and use `cb`. If you want to use that variable, get rid of the one inside the `If` block and rename the one outside.

Comment: Also, what's the point of the cast in the second method? What type do you think the `CurrentCell` property is? Even if you did need a cast, why would you be using `TryCast` there?

Comment: More on topic, it's a very bad idea to make changes based on the selection when the user could cancel the edit. If you want to act on the selection change immediately then you should be committing that change immediately and then acting on the `CellValueChanged` event.

Comment: The code I included was an attempt based on an article I found, I just tried copying it and changing the names to my controls and seeing if it works, not that familiar with adding handlers etc. The issue I am having with `CellValueChanged` is, like I mentioned in the question, that the event triggers after the user has clicked off the DGV Cell with ComboBox in it and I'd like it to trigger once a value has been selected within the DGV ComboBox.

Comment: That's what I said, i.e. you need to commit the selection to the cell to raise a `CellValueChanged` event and then act in that event handler. You need to research how to do that, not sit here waiting for someone to tell you how to do it. I just did a web search with some pretty obvious key words and the first result was another question on this very site. It's for C# rather than VB but the principle is obviously the same and the important line of code is almost identical. If I can find that with so little effort, so can you.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thanks, I did try researching again with your advice at looking for `CellValueChanged` event and managed to find a thread which was also in C# (maybe same one you found) and managed to re-create in VB. Will post an answer to my solution now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments from @jmcilhinney I have managed to find a thread which covers this in C#: [Thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652957/what-event-catches-a-change-of-value-in-a-combobox-in-a-datagridviewcell)

My code following a read of the above thread:

```
Private Sub PL_DGV_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles PL_DGV.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged
            'My DGV Combo Box column is second within the grid therefore manually checking for index 1 column.      
            If PL_DGV.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 1 Then
                If PL_DGV.IsCurrentCellDirty Then
                    PL_DGV.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
                End If
            End If
    End Sub
```

So the above triggers the `CellValueChanged` event in which I have added another check for the DGV ComboBox column as I only need to run a the specific function when that column is is edited:

```
Private Sub PL_DGV_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles PL_DGV.CellValueChanged
            If PL_DGV.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 1 Then
                    RefreshCarriage(e.RowIndex)
            End If
End Sub
```

Again, thanks to @jmcilhinney for commenting and leading me to the solution of the issue.